# What does a blue arrow located in the tab of an open file mean in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

For `Visual Studio Code` 1.80.2 for a project directory opened.

I am not sure what happened but for just for a file appeared in the tab of the file name a blue arrow located at the left, it as follows:

[image]

- What does it mean?
- How was it added?
- How can I remove it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The three files shown in the Figure are based on `asciidoc` syntax. Just the marked one with the blue arrow  does not have the `.adoc` file extension as the two others (see the Figure again).

To be honest I expected other kind of notification indicating explicitly the situation about the missing file extension and not this blue icon.

Therefore the solution is add the missing `.adoc` file extension

Answer (score 0):

That's the file icon for the editor tab. This particular one is the builtin one (from [the builtin Seti theme](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/tree/main/extensions/theme-seti/icons)) for Markdown files.

If you haven't explicitly set the [language mode](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/identifiers), or the filename's extension doesn't have a language mode association (see the `files.associations` for customization), or the filename has no extension, then VS Code will try to infer the file type based on its contents (see the `workbench.editor.languageDetection` and `workbench.editor.languageDetectionHints` settings. It will also try to use language modes that you have previously used as a detection heuristic- see the `workbench.editor.historyBasedLanguageDetection` and `workbench.editor.preferHistoryBasedLanguageDetection` settings), or use the `files.defaultLanguage` if you have set it to anything. For the content-based detection, you could have gotten into this situation by writing something that looks like it could be markdup for a Markdown file. Ex. [an ATX heading](https://spec.commonmark.org/0.30/#atx-headings) ("`# hello world`"- a bit unfortunate, since many other languages also use `# ...` for inline comments).

Quoting from the defaultSettings.json pseudo-file:

> ```json
> // Controls whether the language in a text editor is automatically detected
> // unless the language has been explicitly set by the language picker.
> // This can also be scoped by language so you can specify which languages
> // you do not want to be switched off of. This is useful for languages
> // like Markdown that often contain other languages that might trick
> // language detection into thinking it's the embedded language and not
> // Markdown.
> "workbench.editor.languageDetection": true,
>
> // When enabled, shows a Status bar Quick Fix when the editor language
> // doesn't match detected content language.
> "workbench.editor.languageDetectionHints": {
>   "untitledEditors": true,
>   "notebookEditors": true
> },
>
> // Enables use of editor history in language detection. This causes
> // automatic language detection to favor languages that have been recently
> // opened and allows for automatic language detection to operate with
> // smaller inputs.
> "workbench.editor.historyBasedLanguageDetection": true,
>
> // When enabled, a language detection model that takes into account editor
> // history will be given higher precedence.
> "workbench.editor.preferHistoryBasedLanguageDetection": false,
> ```

If you meant to add a filename extension to indicate the file association, then do that. If you meant to manually set the editor's language mode, then do that. If you meant neither of those things, you may or may not find it to turn on `workbench.editor.preferHistoryBasedLanguageDetection`.